# Magento remove media folder outside magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, customer, customer-account, media

I have one folder inside media and in that folder we are storing customer related files with the order id. I want to make the folder secure from outside. That's why I want to check every time is customer logged in or not before accessing from anywhere.

Please give me some suggestions so that I can proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can protect this folder with .htacess

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

Also you can allow access for specific IP adding next line

```
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: The main problem is the customer should be allowed to view the file only if the customer is loggedin.